# Joomla 3.1 - Populate backend dropdown box

Tags: joomla

I created a simple module named "Course Date Filter" and added this field in my coursedate_filter.xml file:

```
<field
                name="category"
                type="list"
                default="900"
                label="MOD_COURSEDATE_FILTER_FIELD_CATEGORY_LABEL"
                description="MOD_COURSEDATE_FILTER_FIELD_CATEGORY_DESC" />
```

Now, a select field is shown in my Joomla backend view. What I want to achieve is that this select box is populated with all Joomla categories.

Can someone give me a hint please how I can do this?

Thanks,

enne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

you simple needs to define the correct type and extension:

```
type="category" extension="com_content"
```

This will give you a full list of all the categories from **com_content**

so your final code will look like this:

```
<field
     name="category"
     type="category"
     extension="com_content"
     default="900"
     label="MOD_COURSEDATE_FILTER_FIELD_CATEGORY_LABEL"
     description="MOD_COURSEDATE_FILTER_FIELD_CATEGORY_DESC" 
/>
```

Hope this helps